# Strange behavior exporting UnsignedInteger64 in HDF5 format

Tags: bugs, export, data-format, hdf5-format

The `UnsignedInteger64` data format should be able to encode correctly any integer in $[0,2^{64}-1]$. When using this data format with `Export` in `HDF5` format, is exhibits a strange behavior around $2^{63}$.

The `Export` command I use is (in Mathematica 12)

```
Export["file.h5","/list"->{"Data" -> x, "DataFormat" -> "UnsignedInteger64"}]
```

where `list` is a list of integers. The `Import` command is

```
y=Import["file.h5", "/list"]
```

I used the following cases for `x`:

```
x1 = {2^63};
x3 = {2^63 + 1};
x2 = {2^63 - 1};
x4 = {2^63, 2^63 + 1};
x5 = {2^63 - 1, 2^63 - 2};
x6 = {2^63 - 1, 2^63 + 1};
```

which provide outputs `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4`, `y5` and `y6`, respectively.

The condition that `xi==yi` is met for `i` from 1 to 5, but not for 6. In case 6 the value of `y` is a list of the same `Length` as `x` but where all elements are $2^{63}$.

Q: What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, a bug in HDF5 Export, which we will try to fix in the next release of the Wolfram Language.

A workaround for versions 12.3.1 and below is to use (undocumented) `"InputDataFormat"` sub-element to specify the input type directly and bypass the type inference code:

```
In[1]:= x = {2^63 - 1, 2^63 + 1};

In[2]:= Export["file.h5", "/list" -> {
   "Data" -> x,
   "InputDataFormat" -> "UnsignedInteger64",
   "Dimensions" -> {2}
   }]

Out[2]= "file.h5"

In[3]:= Import["file.h5", {"DataFormat", "/list"}]

Out[3]= "UnsignedInteger64"

In[4]:= Import["file.h5", "/list"]

Out[4]= {9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775809}

In[5]:= % === x

Out[5]= True
```

A minor drawback of using `"InputDataFormat"` is that you must also provide `"Dimensions"` explicitly.

The difference between `"DataFormat"` and `"InputDataFormat"` is that the former specifies the format in which you want to store data in the file and the latter tells `Export` in what format the data is provided. By default, `"InputDataFormat"` is set to `Automatic`, in which case `Export` tries to deduce the type on its own.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if other data formats besides UnsignedInteger64 are affected by this?

Comment: I believe this is specific to UnsignedInteger64.